# SalesforceDx: Can't Authorise scratch Org

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I am not able to authorize Scratch org in Force.com IDE 2. I am getting below error.
[image]

### Detailed log is as below.

eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_131
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

com.salesforce.tools.ide.ui
Error
Sat Nov 04 14:15:02 IST 2017
Operation Failed

com.salesforce.tools.ide.cli.api.SfdxApiException: Cannot start the OAuth redirect server on port Error.

PortInUse: Cannot start the OAuth redirect server on port Error.
    at ALMError (C:\Users\lapworld tech\AppData\Local\sfdx\client\node_modules\salesforce-alm\dist\lib\almError.js:35:19)
    at _checkOsPort.then.catch (C:\Users\lapworld tech\AppData\Local\sfdx\client\node_modules\salesforce-alm\dist\lib\process.js:101:19)
    at tryCatcher (C:\Users\lapworld tech\AppData\Local\sfdx\client\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\lapworld tech\AppData\Local\sfdx\client\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:510:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\lapworld tech\AppData\Local\sfdx\client\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:567:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Users\lapworld tech\AppData\Local\sfdx\client\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:612:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Users\lapworld tech\AppData\Local\sfdx\client\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:687:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (C:\Users\lapworld tech\AppData\Local\sfdx\client\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:138:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (C:\Users\lapworld tech\AppData\Local\sfdx\client\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:148:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (C:\Users\lapworld tech\AppData\Local\sfdx\client\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:781:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:743:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:714:5)
    at com.salesforce.tools.ide.cli.api.SfdxCommand.getSfdxApiException(SfdxCommand.java:205)
    at com.salesforce.tools.ide.cli.api.SfdxCommand.processErrorOutput(SfdxCommand.java:254)
    at com.salesforce.tools.ide.cli.api.SfdxCommand.executeCommand(SfdxCommand.java:168)
    at com.salesforce.tools.ide.cli.api.WebLoginCommand.doCall(WebLoginCommand.java:49)
    at com.salesforce.tools.ide.cli.api.WebLoginCommand.doCall(WebLoginCommand.java:1)
    at com.salesforce.tools.ide.cli.api.SfdxCommand.call(SfdxCommand.java:114)
    at com.salesforce.tools.ide.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerWithProgressDialog.executeInBackground(HandlerWithProgressDialog.java:60)
    at com.salesforce.tools.ide.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerWithProgressDialog.lambda$0(HandlerWithProgressDialog.java:82)
    at com.salesforce.tools.ide.ui.internal.parts.JobProgressMonitorDialog.lambda$0(JobProgressMonitorDialog.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.Job$1.run(Job.java:161)

### at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)

Note, I open the Org but can't authorize it.

Comment: Have you tried working with Dev Hub from the CLI tools yet?

Comment: @Andrew, Well I followed the steps mentioned in the guide. I know that I have installed Salesforce CLI and other pre-requisite. 
But to be frank, i wanted to use GUI & so didn't tried to create project via CLI.

Comment: Sure. I just thought that using the CLI tools may help narrow down the issue to the Force.com IDE or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicates that the port is already in use. In order for a program to listen to a socket, it needs to bind to one of 65,635 ports. Only one copy of one program can use any particular port at one time. Odds are, a previous run started on the same port and never terminated, thus holding that port hostage. Try restarting your computer and then authorizing again. Otherwise, you might already have a program that runs on the default port (1717), in which case, you should create a new Connected App as outlined in [Create a Connected App](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_auth_connected_app.htm).

> 1. Log in to your Dev Hub org.
> 2. From Setup, enter `App Manager` in the Quick Find box to get to the Lightning Experience App Manager.
> 3. In the top-right corner, click **New Connected App**.
> 4. Update the basic information as needed, such as the connected app name and your email address.
> 5. Select **Enable OAuth Settings**.
> 6. For the callback URL, enter `http://localhost:1717/OauthRedirect`.
>      If port 1717 (the default) is already in use on your local machine, specify an available one instead. Make sure to also update your `sfdx-project.json` file by setting the `oauthLocalPort` property to the new port. For example, if you set the callback URL to `http://localhost:1919/OauthRedirect`:
>
>    `"oauthLocalPort" : "1919"`
>
> *(Note: Fixed a typo found in the original documentation)*

Comment: Thanks, I checked there was already one previous authorisation going on in background. However even after cancelling it, the port doesn't get free. 
I have to restart my system. 
Anyways, i got the root cause.

Thanks for the reply.